# .offset() fires multiple times when clicked

Tags: jquery

I want `header.top` to become `position:absolute` when I click on `.icon-search`.

But I also want to calculate the current position (because it's fixed) and overwrite it to the current properties with + `position: absolute`.

But when I do this, it starts to fire `$header.offset()` and `console.log($currentPos.top)` multiple times which causes my `currentPos.top` to be correct at first but then it suddendly changes to 0.

Example in console log:

1800
0 
0 
0

Also when I leave the overwriting part away the console log will show this:

(6) 1800

So for some reason it fires 6 the function 6 times.

```
var $header = $('header.top');
$document.on('click', '.icon-search', function () {

    $currentPos = $header.offset();
    console.log($currentPos.top);

    $header.css("position", "absolute");
    $header.css("top", "currentPos.top");

    $searchBtn.off('click');
    $searchContainer.addClass('search-open');
    $input.val("");
    $input.focus();
});
```

Note: This is put inside a scroll function, maybe this has something to do with it?

```
    $document.on('scroll', function()
    {
        if ($document.scrollTop() > 20)
        {
          //function here
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$header.css("top", "currentPos.top");` this is wrong should be `$currentPos.top + 'px'`

Comment: You are nesting hanlders, so ya it is wrong. Set your click handler outside of scroll handler. And scroll event should be bound to window, not document

Comment: Fixed elements have a static/constant offset even if you scroll. Thats why you get `0`.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, will try this out.

Comment: Nesting the handlers means you are adding the same Click handler multiple times. Every time you scroll, a new Click handler will be added. So if you scroll 6 times, then click, your click will be called 6 times.